# How can I implement in my Django CMS aldryn-theme-standardsite?

Tags: django, themes, django-cms

Anyone can help me? please

How can I implement in my Django CMS aldryn-theme-standardsite?

I have tried running the next command: pip install https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-theme-standardsite/archive/master.zip

http://puu.sh/d1JjT/6e07cfbee2.png

Apparently it is downloaded and installed but, what do I do now? How do I activate on my site?

Thanks!

Comment: what else you tried ? looks you installed ..

Comment: Yes. Seems to have installed but can't find how to activate it in django-cms. In the admin panel there is nothing that refers to the theme. Also I did not find the theme's files for any site.

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CMS_TEMPLATES_DIR` in settings ...

```
CMS_TEMPLATES_DIR: {
    1: '/absolute/path/for/site/1/',
    2: '/absolute/path/for/site/2/',
}
```

Comment: Hello. First of all thanks for your time.

I tried to do what you say. When starting the Django-CMS server does the following:

1. Giving syntax error. Not supported ":" and I changed it to "=".

http://puu.sh/d2hAF/ec5ad47de7.png

2. Follow giving errors.

http://puu.sh/d2hEY/bea008e292.png

What else I can do?

Sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: ok . we were accidental passing in a module so that is the error.!.   can you search in your Media_Root .. contains any theme folder there ???

Comment: This is what is defined in MEDIA_ROOT ... http://puu.sh/d2v5S/dcd1ed7800.png

I must say that in cms installation, I chose the option to use "Twitter bootstrap Theme". Does it affect anything?

Thank you so much.

Comment: actually i was telling you to search inside the media folder .. ! is there any folder named aldryn

Comment: No... there are only two folders containing images uploaded from the cms. aldryn theme folder is located on the route that I specified in template_dir. It is the folder that created the theme installation.